# Log successful commands to a file at current directory

Tags: bash, zsh

I know one can dig in `history` or copy & paste the commands right after one run them. But both ways requires several extra operations. Being a tend-to-be lazy person, I really like to have a feature to log  all commands that were run successfully to a file (e.g .commands.log) for archiving purpose. Failed commands are not of my interest. A bonus point would be to exclude some banal commands starting with `cd`, `ls`, etc, or sensitive information (e.g password).

One way I am thinking is to have a function that actually does dig up `history` and append to the `.commands.log`:

```
savecmd      # save the command just before this
savecmd -l 5 # save last 5 commands
savecmd -t 1 # save commands ran during last 1 hour;
```

This approach does not do anything about return status (success/failure), but I can leave with it if there is no better way.

But  I still prefer the auto-logging daemon

Comment: How do you plan on determining on whether the command is successful or not ?

Comment: Status return, I suppose.

Comment: True, just check $? == 0

Comment: @biocyberman Not necessarily.

Comment: @User112638726: Could you clarify? For me I do not need know precise status outcome of the commands. I want only successful commands because I may type long commands with typos, and want to type it again. It is no use to save those commands with typos.

Comment: For example `touch` used to return 0 for everything whether it was successful or not. Checking the return code does not guarantee the command was successful.

Comment: That's right. Some commands have unconventional return code. But that is OK.

Comment: Are you using Linux?  The reason I ask is that you could log via `script -f` to a named pipe.

Comment: @cdarke `script` not only writes all commands, failed or not, but also everything printed, including even escape codes. That's definitely not what the OP is looking for. Plus, it's not something invented for Linux.

Comment: @4ae1e1: I am aware of all your points.  `script` itself in not specific to Linux, but the `-f` option is (at least to the GNU version).  The `-f` option allows data to be passed through a named pipe and parsed, rather than to a regular file, it would be a simple task to filter out the commands.  Not having the `-f` buffers everything and makes the task more difficult.

Comment: @cdarke Not sure about "it would be a simple task to filter out the commands", especially since the OP asks for filtering based on `$?`. Otherwise `history` is more than enough; as far as I can tell, `script -f` just complicates the task without doing extra good. You set out to solve one problem, but now you have two.